# Whats a Good Example of Interconnected Smart Contracts?

Tags: plutus, smart-contract, validator, monad

In the Contract Monad we have the use of w s e a. Now w is used to connect contracts is there a good example of how this is done, in particular how to validate a contract using the w of another contract?